# Unexpected data found.\nTrailing data

Tags: laravel, php-carbon

I got this error:

**"Unexpected data found.\nTrailing data"**

It says that it comes from this LN on my **update** function:

```
$fe_ini = Carbon::createFromFormat('d/m/Y H:i', $request->fecha_inicial);
```

fecha_inicial comes from my blade:

```
<div class="col-md-4">
  <label>Fecha inicial</label>
  <input type="datetime-local" name="fecha_inicial" value="2018-01-31T18:00:00" class="form-control input-lg" ng-model="descuento.fecha_inicial" ng-disabled ="desAll" required>
</div>
```

My **store** function says:

```
$fecha_inicial  = Carbon::createFromFormat('d/m/Y H:i', $request->fecha_inicial);
```

Could you help me to find out what am I doing wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: the date format of your input doesn't match what you are trying to create from, they are 2 completely different formats

Answer (score 2):

As Lagbox says in [their comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73395860/unexpected-data-found-ntrailing-data/73396644#comment129616576_73395860), your date formats don't match:

The value on your input, `2018-01-31T18:00:00`, is not in the format you're passing to `createFromFormat()` which is `'d/m/Y H:i'`.

I suggest just moving to `Carbon::parse()`:

```
$fecha_inicial  = Carbon::parse($request->fecha_inicial);
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by doing this:

```
$fecha_inicial  = Carbon::createFromFormat('d/m/Y, H:i:s', $request->fecha_inicial)->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

I checked my Payload and the data came with a comma ',' right after the year like this:

> '13/09/2022, 11:38:53'

So what I did was to add a comma too in the format from createFromFormat method. Plus, I added `->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')` to convert it.

Thanks.